# How to run C# exe file created by Visual Studio in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exe, windows-10

I have Visual Studio enterprise 2015 installed on Windows 10.
I can run the following Console Application Hello world (written in C#) program from within VS
and I can see the console print out the text "Hello world!", but when I 
tried to run the executable file:

```
\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hello\Hello\bin\Debug\Hello.exe
```

from outside the VS
by double click on it, nothing is happen.

```
namespace Hello
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Actually I got this problem after upgrading my Windows 8.1 to 10, before that every think was working fine.
I tried the following solutions but all doesn't help:

- Reinstalling VS 2015.
- Tried to use an older version of VS 2013.
- Removing MS C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) and (x86) and reinstalled again.
- Rebuild the program to get the Release file to used instead of the the debug one.
- Reset all settings from Tools/Import and Export Settings..
- Added the path of the Microsoft.NET to the environmental variable.
- Using a previous version of Microsoft.NET by select it from within VS.

Any Idea?

Comment: That program is a console program, it needs some sort of console. Open a command window. `CD` to the directory containing the `.exe`. Then run the `.exe` in that command window.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Please read my others comments!

Answer (score 4):

I copied your code in visual studio in windows 10 and builded the application. It worked.

When I opened it in windows and double click on exe file it worked again.

But one thing I wanted to point out just in case. Check the first two files here.

The top one is the executable.
2nd file seems like it has an .exe extension but it is configuration file. Sometimes we all miss some simple things. I am not sure but wanted to show may be helps :)

[image]

If everything you tried did not work, try to recreate a project and copy paste the code files.

Good luck with theese small bugs :)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I spent two days to solve this problem, but now it is solved,please see my answer

Comment: I am happy for you :)

Comment: I literally logged in after many years just to upvote you - I got confused of the .exe extension after returning to coding since many years :) Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

OK, First I would like to thank every one tried to help, I just found that my antivirus "Avast" for some reason blocked all exe file from VS! after disabling the antivirus, all exe files of VS work fine.

Comment: mark my answer correct i found the route their for your answer so that all feel simple while searrching

Answer (score 1):

its

1-off smart screen

2-off antivirus

3-enable administrator account

thankyou and markup

Comment: you are not staying on a screen

Comment: I used your solution, but still not working! As I said before I can't run any other exe file created by VS!

Comment: ohh you are using previous version of .net frame work change it by going to project properties to latest one , donot mark down please if you want cooperation there

Comment: Do you have anything going on in your Program.cs (or App.xaml.cs depending on type of app). Also are you 100% certain that there is no message at all in the Event Viewer

Comment: windows smart screen is off

Comment: I didn't marked down your answer! and I appreciate your tring to help, Yes ther is no message at all in the Event Viewer,  how to know if the smart screen is off?

Comment: Ok I just checked the smart screen and it is already on! It is on "Get administrator approval before running an unrecognized app from the Internet (recommended)"

Comment: off the smart screen [smart screen off link](http://www.howtogeek.com/75356/how-to-turn-off-or-disable-the-smartscreen-filter-in-windows-8/) also markuo by your self

Comment: only windows is not giving you access to file also go to CMD and enable administrator account then login as administrator google *how to enable hidden administrator account*

Comment: Disable antivirus also

Comment: can you please mark my answer correct so that others visiting feels simple to get answer

Comment: Hello @office302, I tried your solution, but my exe still does not work. I am using .net 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1 for my windows app and using Windows 10 to run that exe. Please help me out here.